# Virtualenv can not inherit GetSitePackages() Attribute

Tags: python, virtualenv, osx-elcapitan, tensorflow

I just installed TensorFlow under VirtualEnv on Mac OSX El Capitan. Now I am trying to understand the structure by following examples given in tensorflow.org website.

I am new to python and its syntax. But as far as I can figure out the attribute called getsitepackages() is kind of important in order to list modules' attributes easily. But with its default python and virtualenv version on el capitan, it seems that virtualenv can not inherit `getsitepackages()` attribute of the module called "site".

Hence I couldn't run the simple example command (`python -c 'import site; print("\n".join(site.getsitepackages()))'`) to locate tensorflow libraries.

I guess this is a known bug but I couldn't find a way to solve this issue. I just wonder if anyone has already came up with and solved this problem?

P.S. Outside the virtualenv `getsitepackages()` just works fine. But in the virtualenv I get the following error

```
python -c 'import site; print("\n".join(site.getsitepackages()))'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "< string >", line 1, in < module >

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getsitepackages'
```

Comment: are you running that with the virtual environment that you created already activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with `sites.py` which dates all the way back to 2012. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/355).

Have a stab at trying to create the virtualenv using a different python version. For example:

```
virtualenv -p python3 virtualenvname
```

It's worth checking what python version you're running (`python --version`). This seems to only be a problem with `python2.7` - earlier versions like `python2.6` do not experience this problem however they lack a lot of useful packages that were added in `python2.7`.

My recommendation would be to run it under `python3` or `python3.4`.
TensorFlow seems to support `python3` with the [0.6.0 release](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/0.6.0).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wanted to get it work with default pip and python2.7 installation at first hand. As @Hevlatska recommended, python3 and pip3 installation solves the issue.

Comment: @ŞükrüOzan if you're happy with the solution would you mind accepting it as a valid answer? :)